# RxJava. Correct way to generate ViewObject by few sources

Tags: java, android, sqlite, rx-java, viewmodel

I have two entity classes, which stores in **SQLite**: `UserEntity` and `SessionInfoEntity`:

```
public class UserEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    // ....
}

public class SessionInfoEntity{
    private Long id;

    private Date beginSessionDate;
    private Date endSessionDate;
    // ....
}
```

User can have many sessions (one-to-many relation).

I have a repository, which provides necessary methods to get data (RxJava observables) from my SQLite database:

```
public class MyRepository{
    public Observable<List<UserEntity>> getAllUsers(){/* ... */}
    public Observable<SessionInfoEntity> getLastSessionInfoForUser(Long userId){/* ... */} // returns info of last session for user with id=userId
}
```

I need to generate next **ViewObject** for each User, using `MyRepository`'s methods and **RxJava**:

```
public class UserViewObject {
    private String userName;
    private Integer lastSessionDurationInHours;
    // ....
}
```

In turns out that I need to call `getLastSessionInfoForUser()` for each User in order to create `UserViewObject`.

**QUESTION:** How I can generate `UserViewObject` using **RxJava** correctly?

I'm trying to start doing this this way:

```
myRepository
            .getAllUsers()
            .flatMap(lst -> Observable.from(lst))
            .flatMap(ve -> getLastSessionInfoForUser(ve.getId())
            .map(lse -> /* ?????  */) // In this operator I lose access to current user => I can't generate UserViewObject, because I haven't access to ve.getUserName() method
```

**P.S.:** I can't write method in MyRepository, which will be returns object with whole information.

**P.P.S.:** In the future, new methods will be added that are related to the User entity (like `getLastSessionInfoForUser()` method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the map in the last `flatMap`. Like that you have access to `ve`.

```
myRepository
        .getAllUsers()
        .flatMap(lst -> Observable.from(lst))
        .flatMap(ve -> getLastSessionInfoForUser(ve.getId()).map(lse -> /* ... */))
```

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for your answer! Let's say, in order to create UserViewObject I need to use 3 or more observable methods of MyRepository (for example: getLastSessionInfoForUser(id)  + getFriendsCountForUser(id) + getSubscribersCountForUser(id) + getPostsListsForUser(id) + ....... e.t.c.). How I will solve problems of nesting mappers in this case?

Comment: You can use `zip` in the last `flatMap` for "zipping" multiple observable result into one http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html. Would you like an example code?

Comment: No. All OK. Thank you lot!